# Does AWS not allow outbound SSH connections?

Tags: ssh, amazon-web-services, ssh-tunnel, amazon-vpc

I was wondering if Amazon Web Services disallows outbound SSH connections from public facing EC2 instances? I have an SSH Bastion on a public subnet with an Elastic IP setup to where I can can successfully tunnel connections into my VPCs but when I create a Security Group rule to allow outbound connections to a remote server and try to make a connection I get:

ssh: Connection timed out

I've done some searching, and found this question unanswered:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=205579

Edit: I can SSH from the SSH-Bastion but ONLY to other EC2 instances that belong to me. Connecting to an external server not on AWS is currently not working for me.

Edit2: I can also make outbound connections to the internet through an Internet Gateway. Running works

```
curl www.google.com 
telnet www.google.com 80
```

The outbound security rules for the bastion look like this:

```
22 (SSH)    [internal AWS Private subnet range]
22 (SSH)    [external linode ip]
80 (HTTP)   0.0.0.0/0
443 (HTTPS) 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: I have an ec2 instance and can make outbound connections

Comment: are you sshing to another ec2 instance in the same region?

Comment: @lain I can make outbound connections to the internet, I just can't make an SSH connection on a remote server outside of AWS completely.

Comment: @Mike I'm not SSHing to another ec2 instance at all, its actually to a remote linode.

Answer (score 2):

Nope, AWS doesn't inherently block outbound SSH.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @wombie, hmmm I shall keep investigating. I'm not saying ALL outbound SSH connections because I can SSH from the SSH-Bastion but ONLY to other EC2 instances that belong to me. Connecting to an external server not on AWS is currently not working for me.

Comment: Please add diagnostically relevant information to your question as an edit, not to an answer as a comment.  Also, it might be worth getting a font that can distinguish between an 'l' and an 'i' character.

Comment: @wombie edited 8) as for the font thing, I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Tomek: My name is not "wombie", it's "womble".

Comment: haha I see, sorry about that! Anyways, how do those outbound configurations for the bastion security group look to you?